# ASP.NET - Different threads writing to the same file causing problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking

I've got a method which performs a delete and create file.  there are issues with the threads all trying to access the file at the same time.

How can i limit access to the file?

```
public static Save(string file)
{
  //1.Perform Delete
  //2.Perform Write 
}
```

Note that the method is static so is it possible to lock the process within the static method?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
public static void Save(string file)
{
    lock(_syncRoot) {
        //1.Perform Delete
        //2.Perform Write 
    }
}
```

Or you could use the [MethodImplAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) which puts a `lock` around the whole method body:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static void Save(string file)
{
    //1.Perform Delete
    //2.Perform Write 
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! The only thing I would do different is declare _syncRoot as readonly.

Comment: While this suggestion will work, it potentially introduces a lot of contention into a website. It is probably worth pointing this out in the answer, as if every single request to a page results in this being called, performance will suffer.

Comment: What will happen if the method threw an exception, will the lock automatically release?

Comment: @Wololo, the lock construct is analogous to `Monitor.Enter(lockObj); try { /* code */ } finally { Monitor.Exit(lockObj) }`, so this should pretty much answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a lock on a static object.

```
private static Object saveLock = new Object();

public static Save(string file)
{
   lock (saveLock )
   {
     //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590/lock-keyword-in-c) which discusses the use of the `lock` statement.